# Top Unity panel bar and Unity launcher bar disappeared after Compiz

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Bit.

There is two Unity interface `Ubuntu` and `Ubuntu 2D` on login screen. I'm always using `Ubuntu` .

Today i installed *CompizConfig Setting Manager* and try a few effect etc. for just fun. And than i want to back to my old (original) Ubuntu interface. So, i clicked to **Reset to Defaults** on *Preferences* screen . And suddenly top panel bar and the launcher on the left have disappeared (look that badly drawn white arrows, pointing these bars). Also dashboard not activating when press to Windows key on my keyboard.

[image]

When i choose `Ubuntu 2D`, it's normal. There is no problem. But i want normal 'Ubuntu` interface, back. What should i do?

Comment: This is not clearly a duplicate.  The other article was written two years ago when there were clear issues with Unity, and it _recommends_ installing compiz-config and playing with ccsm.  In this case I believe a simple unity --reset to clear the settings changed in compiz-config should be all that is required.

Comment: @fabricator4 Sure. Look at the second answer.

Comment: My question closed because of *duplicated question* . But that question's accepted answer doesn't solve my problem. @fabricator4's answer solve my problem. Because of this, i think these are different questions. BECAUSE ANSWERS DIFFERENT. That question's answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: On the other question, the answers are likely to confuse a newcomer. Although the correct answer is in there, much of it is outdated and is too involved when only a simple unity --reset is required.

Comment: Instead of reopening this, I suggest fixing the other question.